# How to Configure InstallShield to Remove a file that has already been removed

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2009

So basically we released a Recovery image that had a file deleted that was installed as part of our installshield installer.

Now that we have a software update when we go to install on top of the installation with the missing file, InstallShield tries to unregister the exe giving an error message.

The file should have been removed from the installer rather by hand, but now I need a way to not show this error message since the file doesnt exist on the system.

I have tried removing the file from the Component in questions, as well as removing the Component entirely. In both cases the Error message still occurs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options that I can think of ...

1. Create a patch (msp) from the original installation. The patch should update the condition of the custom action that unregisters the EXE. If it is being registered/unregistered via SelfReg table, then the patch should be created by removing the relevant entries from that table. Ensure that the patch is executed before the upgrade. (A bootstrapper exe could do that.)
2. Have the original exe in the "Support Files" section, add a custom action to copy it to the original folder and schedule the custom action before "RemoveExistingProducts" action. Condition it such that it gets executed only on upgrade.

--Jag